# How to make the falling blocks entity permanent in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In the Java edition, you can make them permanent via commands by summoning them with no time tag, and setting `NoGravity` to `true`, but is that possible in the Bedrock Edition, using an NBT editor?